# How to Navigate to other Screen using Carousel

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to have a carousel with 5 photos and when I press any of the images I want to navigate to a different screen. I watched many videos but couldn't find any solutions. I used `carousel_slider` package.

```
CarouselSlider(
  CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
  items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber
          ),
          child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
        );
      },
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

Imagine I have 5 different pages and when I press any of the pictures in the carousel then I should be navigated to a particular page. If I use a Gesture detector how can I navigate him using navigator.push?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ManuallyControlledSlider from 
https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart but change onPressed callback inside
Iterable -> RaisedButton to navigate on specific page.